# Story of a Witch Boy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a story about a young warlock who flies around at night with witch friends.  He is callous and unfeeling until he befriends and falls in love with a Quaker? or Amish? girl he meets at a haystack one night. The story spoke to the clothing and bonnets women wore, and hard farm life.  He gives up his powers to become human and they marry.  He does not adapt to the human world well.  She gives birth to a clawed and winged creature that is thrown into a fire by the midwives and then she stumbles to the haystack where they met and she dies.  His witch friends restore his power, but he loses all memory of her. His last act is to kick with mild curiosity at her body before he flies off. This short story or possibly play was in the early 1970's literature class at my high school, but I do not know how old the story is or if it was a translation from folklore from another country.  Hope someone can help, been looking for years.

Comment: Thank you Denny!!!!!! I cannot tell you how happy this makes me!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a play; my college put it on back in the 1960s, and I remember it well from that: [*Dark of the Moon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_of_the_Moon_(play)).

> Dark of the Moon is a dramatic stage play by Howard Richardson and William Berney. The play was produced on Broadway in 1945
>
> This perennial favorite is based on the haunting folk ballad of "Barbara Allen." Employing a large cast and imaginative settings in the Smoky Mountains, it recounts the story of John, a strange "witch boy" who upon first beholding the beautiful Barbara Allen immediately falls in love. He is given human form to woo and marry her on the condition that she remain true to him. The marriage is consummated and Barbara gives birth to a witch child whom the townspeople destroy in a superstitious frenzy. During a religious revival Barbara is led to betray John thus breaking their spell of love. As she dies, he returns forever to the world of the mountain witches.